# script to keep retrying a heredoc psql query until it succeeds with until loop

Tags: linux, postgresql, bash, loops, psql

I run a multi sql query transaction through psql manually as follows:

```sh
psql <<EOF
BEGIN;
Query1;
Query2;
COMMIT;
EOF
```

The issue here is that sometimes my transaction fails and need to keep retrying manually until success. This becomes a little tedious when it needs to repeatedly be done.

Is there a way to achieve this using until ?

My working attempt so far is:

```sh
until psql --file transaction.sql
do
    sleep 5
done
```

However, this requires an extra file outside the scope of this script.

is there a way to make it work in the following fashion:

```sh
# this is currently not working for me.
until psql <<EOF
   BEGIN;
   Query1;
   Query2;
   COMMIT;
EOF
do
    sleep 5
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using a function.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

my_function(){
{
psql <<EOF
BEGIN;
Query1;
Query2;
COMMIT;
EOF
} && return 0
return 1
}

until my_function; do
  sleep 5
done
```